# Windows 10 batch file dns

Tags: dns, windows-10, batch

I have two batch-files, one to change my DNS to Unblock-US, and one to reset it to DHCP.
These worked perfectly in Windows 7 and 8/8.1, but after upgrading to Windows 10 i can no longer reset it to DHCP.

Unblock-US batch:

```
netsh interface ipv4 set dns "Ethernet 2" static 208.122.23.22
netsh interface ipv4 add dns "Ethernet 2" 208.122.23.23 index=2
ipconfig /flushdns
```

DHCP batch:

```
netsh interface ipv4 set dns "Ethernet 2" static dhcp
netsh interface ipv4 add dns "Ethernet 2" dhcp index=1
ipconfig /flushdns
```

Anyone have an idea what may be wrong?

Comment: Do you get an error message? Have you tried running as Admin?

Comment: Is the adapter definitely called Ethernet 2?

Comment: @DavidPostill: No error message, it just won't change it to DHCP.
I'm running as admin

Comment: @CharlesH: Yes, it is Ethernet 2. It will change to Unblock-US, but not back to DHCP

Comment: In `netsh interface ipv4 set dns "Ethernet 2"` you should use either `static` or `dhcp` but not both together, see `netsh interface ipv4 set dns /?`

Answer (score 2):

change this:

```
netsh interface ipv4 set dns "Ethernet 2" static dhcp
```

to

```
netsh interface ipv4 set dns "Ethernet 2" dhcp
```

remember to execute this with Admin privileges and the second line is superfluous.